# Set field to a shared value

Tags: jackson, jackson-databind

I have a class that looks like this:

```
class Data {
    @JsonCreator
    public Data(@JsonProperty("string") String s, Widget w) {
         string = s;
         widget = w;
    }
    String string;
    Widget widget;
}
```

I want to deserialize it from this from JSON like

```
{
    "string": "string value"
}
```

When deserializing, I want to set `widget` to a shared instance. I have that instance when I create the object mapper, but I can not see how to tell Jackson to use this instance.

I see `JsonDeserialize.getNullValue` and `getEmptyValue`, but those look like they are for handling

```
{
   "string": "string value", "widget": null 
}
```

which is not the JSON that I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try `@JacksonInject`:

```java
public class Data {

    @JacksonInject
    public Widget widget;

    ...
}
```

And then use as follows:

```java
Widget widget = ...

InjectableValues injectable = new InjectableValues.Std().addValue(Widget.class, widget);
Data data = new ObjectMapper().reader(injectable).forType(Data.class).readValue(json);
```

Comment: That was what I was looking for.  If you always want the injection, then `new ObjectMapper().setInjectableValues(injectable)` does what you want.